# Load different methods depending on which view is being browsed LARAVEL

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Trying to load different views and methods depending on which view the user is browsing.

Views:

```
public function edit()
{    
    if("SOMETHING")return View::make('store_edit');
    If("SOMETHING")return View::make('product_edit');
}
```

Methods:

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    if(SOMETHING){
       $store = Store::find($id);
       $store->delete();
       return redirect('/store');
     }
    if(SOMETHING){
       $product = Product::find($id);
       $product->delete();
       return redirect('/product');
      }
}
```

What can be used in the `if()` statements depending on which view is browsed in order to delete the right item and not having to rewrite the functions for each table.

Comment: Product and Store are two different model, DO NOT use same controller for both ,

Comment: I agree with Mahdi Younesi, you will regret in future if you reuse the same, very minimalistic controller code. Because at some point, you will have more complex requirements to implement.

Comment: Alright, thank you, will take your advice.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a simple way to get information about which view was displayed in a previous request, and that's probably not what you want. You should create separate controllers/routes for both "products" and "store". Then you can do away with that view logic altogether.

To somewhat answer your question, you can [access information about the current route](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing#accessing-the-current-route) with the `Route` facade.

```
$route = Route::current();
$name = Route::currentRouteName();
$action = Route::currentRouteAction();
```

Answer (score 0):

Read Laravel routing:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing#route-parameters

Route

```
Route::get('something/{param}', 'SomeController@edit');
```

Controller

```
...
    public function edit($param) {
        if ($param === $expectedParam) {...} else {...}
    }
```

Also you can make $param optional:

Route

```
Route::get('something/{param?}', 'SomeController@edit');
```

Controller *(don't forget to give a default value)*

```
...
    public function edit($param = null) {
        if ($param === $expectedParam) {...} else {...}
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please do not use same controller for diferent models.
if has diferent view and diferent functions this HAVE to has diferent controllers

Again, Laravel is a beautiful framework, dont do this!